# Select count of distinct column in table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, distinct

Lets say I have a sql table in the format:

```
id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
action TINYINT NOT NULL,
user_id INT NOT NULL
```

I would like to build a query that produces the same result as the following:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT COUNT(*), action FROM table WHERE action=1 AND user_id=1),
    (SELECT COUNT(*), action FROM table WHERE action=2 AND user_id=1),
    (SELECT COUNT(*), action FROM table WHERE action=3 AND user_id=1),
    ...
    (SELECT COUNT(*), action FROM table WHERE action=n AND user_id=1)
```

(1<->n is simply the range of `action`)

But without all the redundancy and inefficiency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, this is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT   action, COUNT(*)
FROM     your_table
WHERE    user_id = 1
GROUP BY action
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use GROUP BY:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(*) as Count, 
action as Action 
FROM table1 
WHERE user_id = 1
GROUP BY action
```

This will produce a row for each unique action, and in that row have a column Count being the count of rows with that unique action.

In the example above, all user_id conditions are =1, so if this is case you can include it as in the query, otherwise you can form your own condition based on the needed values.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(id), action FROM table WHERE user_id=1 GROUP BY action
```

HTH, though I am a bit confused if this is what you are looking for.